# How to display pre-rendered animations in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, gif

I want to use pre-redered animations in a website. The animation consists of a set of images that should be displayed at 30fps.
I currently use gifs but it seems like there is no real way to properly time them (resetting does not always work).

What is the best way to do this?

Here is my current project as an example of how gifs don't work. [Click](http://marian42.no-ip.biz/hex/) (click the third button to start the game). Sometimes gifs just don't start to play or they start at another frame than the first one. It works slightly better in Chrome than in Firefox, as its at least consistent in when they work and when not, but in Firefox this happens quite random.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know of for this kind of use-case is to use sprites and play them back in a canvas tag.

The reason is you gain control over the playback as well as leverage GPU support that gifs generally dont have.

Luckily there are a ton of tutorials on the subject. Try this one [here](http://www.webappers.com/2013/02/08/how-to-make-sprite-animations-with-html5-canvas/)